Trino with Spilling and Alluxio Caching makes a large number of requests to the Object Storage

I have a local setup of Trino, Hive Metastore, and Minio storage. I have enabled and configured Alluxio caching and Disk Spilling on Trino. The number of requests made to the object storage is higher than expected. Given that I am only testing on a few megabytes of Parquet files.
What could be the problem? and the solution?
Here are my configurations in /etc/trino/config.properties .
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
catalog.management=${ENV:CATALOG_MANAGEMENT}
query.max-memory=2GB
query.max-memory-per-node=700MB
exchange.http-client.max-requests-queued-per-destination=999999
scheduler.http-client.max-requests-queued-per-destination=999999
exchange.http-client.request-timeout=30s
task.info-update-interval=2s
spill-enabled=true
spiller-spill-path=/tmp/spill
spiller-max-used-space-threshold=0.7
spiller-threads= 16
max-spill-per-node=100GB
query-max-spill-per-node=100GB
aggregation-operator-unspill-memory-limit=15MB
spill-compression-codec=LZ4
spill-encryption-enabled=false

Here are my catalog configurations in /etc/trino/catalog/hive.properties
connector.name=hive
hive.metastore=thrift
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://hive-metastore:9083
hive.s3.path-style-access=true
hive.s3.endpoint=http://minio:9000
hive.s3.aws-access-key=XXX
hive.s3.aws-secret-key=XXX
hive.non-managed-table-writes-enabled=true
hive.s3.ssl.enabled=false
hive.s3.max-connections=1000
hive.metastore.thrift.client.read-timeout=3000s
hive.timestamp-precision=MILLISECONDS
hive.collect-column-statistics-on-write=false
hive.storage-format=PARQUET
hive.security=allow-all
fs.cache.enabled=true
fs.cache.directories=/tmp/cache
fs.cache.max-disk-usage-percentages=70
fs.cache.ttl=32d
fs.cache.preferred-hosts-count=5
fs.cache.page-size=15MB

Thanks in advance.

-- Edit: Test with both cach and spilling disabled

Disabling caching and spilling, has affected the latency and throughput, and caused far more GetObject requests:


-- Edit: Cache Tracing --

I have enabled cache tracing, and the cache is being hit.




Instruction to enable tracing were found at: File System Cache-Monitoring
Setup in Docker Compose is simply:


  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    hostname: jaeger
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"
      - "4317:4317"
    environment:
      - COLLECTOR_OTLP_ENABLED=true


And /etc/trino/config.properties
################################# Tracing
tracing.enabled=true
tracing.exporter.endpoint=http://jaeger:4317


-- Edit: Provide more context Part II--

Based on Slack chat, the following has been confirmed:

Alluxio is used internally in Trino, so no need to follow further tutorials on setting Alluxio standalone/edge etc.
Caching is supported only on workers, but still my original problem happens when I am using one master and three workers, and I revised the configurations.
I have disabled spilling, and still the Minio traffic is still high.

On Trino startup, I get:
024-05-08T09:14:37.105Z INFO    main    Bootstrap   hive.s3.security-mapping.refresh-period              ----        ----                  How often to refresh the security mapping configuration
2024-05-08T09:14:37.106119355Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.105Z INFO    main    Bootstrap   hive.s3.security-mapping.iam-role-credential-name    ----        ----                  Name of the extra credential used to provide IAM role
2024-05-08T09:14:37.106120682Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.105Z INFO    main    Bootstrap   jmx.base-name                                        ----        ----
2024-05-08T09:14:37.237666777Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.237Z INFO    main    alluxio.client.file.cache.PageStore Opening PageStore with option=alluxio.client.file.cache.store.PageStoreOptions@780e214b
2024-05-08T09:14:37.256328387Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.256Z INFO    pool-51-thread-1    alluxio.client.file.cache.LocalCacheManager Restoring PageStoreDir (/tmp/alluxio_cache/LOCAL)
2024-05-08T09:14:37.257456265Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.257Z INFO    pool-51-thread-1    alluxio.client.file.cache.LocalCacheManager PageStore (/tmp/alluxio_cache/LOCAL) restored with 0 pages (0 bytes), discarded 0 pages (0 bytes)
2024-05-08T09:14:37.257498782Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.257Z INFO    pool-51-thread-1    alluxio.client.file.cache.LocalCacheManager Cache is in READ_WRITE.
2024-05-08T09:14:37.552235866Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.551Z INFO    main    org.ishugaliy.allgood.consistent.hash.HashRing  Ring [hash_ring_8605] created: hasher [METRO_HASH], partitionRate [1000]
2024-05-08T09:14:37.566095594Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.565Z INFO    main    org.ishugaliy.allgood.consistent.hash.HashRing  Ring [hash_ring_8605]: node [TrinoNode[nodeIdentifier=5b97f235d043, hostAndPort=172.23.0.12:8080]] added
2024-05-08T09:14:37.721904967Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.721Z DEBUG   main    io.trino.connector.CoordinatorDynamicCatalogManager -- Added catalog hive using connector hive --
2024-05-08T09:14:37.724651195Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.724Z INFO    main    io.trino.security.AccessControlManager  Using system access control: default
2024-05-08T09:14:37.735207694Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.734Z INFO    main    io.trino.server.Server  Server startup completed in 14.36s
2024-05-08T09:14:37.735276670Z 2024-05-08T09:14:37.734Z INFO    main    io.trino.server.Server  ======== SERVER STARTED ========


-- Edit: Provide more context Part I--

The test simply runs a few simple queries in a loop, so regardless of partitioning or queries joins cardinalities, the caching should have been triggered.

By "expected" I meant, I would have expected a 10-megabyte dataset not to cause 60 GB of traffic, as in the screenshot below.

I assume that the Alluxio cache is bypassed altogether, so I doubt that it is not only a matter of configuration, as one might infer from:
Trino: File System Cache

By consulting more references, it's clear that more steps should be included:

Alluxio: Running Trino with Alluxio - Edge
Alluxio: Running Trino with Alluxio - Stable
Trino: Alluxio Tutorial 
Alluxio: Integrate Alluxio


Besides, I doubt compatibility issues, since I am on Trino 445. The Alluxio docs mentions that the step were only tested against an earlier version of Trino:
Deploy Trino. This guide is tested with Trino-352.


Here is a distribution of the requests trino makes to Minio bypassing any caching, I include it in case it hints Trino team to an optimization idea, especially head requests are triggered very often:


Finally, after following the steps in the above mentioned tutorials, the following error occurs:
trino> CREATE SCHEMA hive.lakehouse
    ->     WITH (location = 'alluxio://alluxio-leader:19998/lakehouse');
Query 20240508_071745_00002_vyeug failed: Invalid location URI: alluxio://alluxio-leader:19998/lakehouse


Logs:
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.210Z    DEBUG   dispatcher-query-4      io.trino.security.AccessControl Invocation of checkCanSetUser(principal=Optional[trino], userName='trino') succeeded in 27.47us
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.210Z    DEBUG   dispatcher-query-4      io.trino.security.AccessControl Invocation of checkCanExecuteQuery(identity=Identity{user='trino', principal=trino}, queryId=20240508_071745_00002_vyeug) succeeded in 13.49us
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.211Z    DEBUG   dispatcher-query-5      io.trino.execution.QueryStateMachine    Query 20240508_071745_00002_vyeug is QUEUED
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.211Z    DEBUG   dispatcher-query-1      io.trino.execution.QueryStateMachine    Query 20240508_071745_00002_vyeug is WAITING_FOR_RESOURCES
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.212Z    DEBUG   dispatcher-query-1      io.trino.execution.QueryStateMachine    Query 20240508_071745_00002_vyeug is DISPATCHING
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.212Z    DEBUG   dispatcher-query-1      io.trino.execution.QueryStateMachine    Query 20240508_071745_00002_vyeug is RUNNING
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.213Z    DEBUG   Query-20240508_071745_00002_vyeug-172   io.trino.security.AccessControl Invocation of checkCanCreateSchema(context=SecurityContext{identity=Identity{user='trino', principal=trino}, queryId=20240508_071745_00002_vyeug}, schemaName=hive.lakehouse, properties={location=alluxio://alluxio-leader:19998/lakehouse}) succeeded in 68.04us
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.223Z    DEBUG   Query-20240508_071745_00002_vyeug-172   io.trino.plugin.hive.metastore.thrift.ThriftHiveMetastoreClient Invocation of getDatabase(name='lakehouse') took 7.32ms and failed with NoSuchObjectException(message:database hive.lakehouse)
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.224Z    DEBUG   dispatcher-query-1      io.trino.execution.QueryStateMachine    Query 20240508_071745_00002_vyeug is FAILED
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.224Z    DEBUG   Query-20240508_071745_00002_vyeug-172   io.trino.execution.QueryStateMachine    Query 20240508_071745_00002_vyeug failed
2024-05-08 09:17:45 io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Invalid location URI: alluxio://alluxio-leader:19998/lakehouse
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.plugin.hive.HiveMetadata.lambda$createSchema$22(HiveMetadata.java:954)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.plugin.hive.HiveMetadata.createSchema(HiveMetadata.java:949)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.plugin.base.classloader.ClassLoaderSafeConnectorMetadata.createSchema(ClassLoaderSafeConnectorMetadata.java:417)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.tracing.TracingConnectorMetadata.createSchema(TracingConnectorMetadata.java:348)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.metadata.MetadataManager.createSchema(MetadataManager.java:769)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.tracing.TracingMetadata.createSchema(TracingMetadata.java:373)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.execution.CreateSchemaTask.internalExecute(CreateSchemaTask.java:128)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.execution.CreateSchemaTask.execute(CreateSchemaTask.java:82)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.execution.CreateSchemaTask.execute(CreateSchemaTask.java:54)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.execution.DataDefinitionExecution.start(DataDefinitionExecution.java:146)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.execution.SqlQueryManager.createQuery(SqlQueryManager.java:272)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.dispatcher.LocalDispatchQuery.startExecution(LocalDispatchQuery.java:145)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.dispatcher.LocalDispatchQuery.lambda$waitForMinimumWorkers$2(LocalDispatchQuery.java:129)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.airlift.concurrent.MoreFutures.lambda$addSuccessCallback$12(MoreFutures.java:570)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.airlift.concurrent.MoreFutures$3.onSuccess(MoreFutures.java:545)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1137)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.$gen.Trino_445____20240508_071639_2.run(Unknown Source)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
2024-05-08 09:17:45 Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "alluxio"
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3553)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.hdfs.TrinoFileSystemCache.createFileSystem(TrinoFileSystemCache.java:155)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.hdfs.TrinoFileSystemCache$FileSystemHolder.createFileSystemOnce(TrinoFileSystemCache.java:298)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.hdfs.TrinoFileSystemCache.getInternal(TrinoFileSystemCache.java:140)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.hdfs.TrinoFileSystemCache.get(TrinoFileSystemCache.java:91)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ForwardingFileSystemCache.get(ForwardingFileSystemCache.java:39)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:557)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.hdfs.HdfsEnvironment.lambda$getFileSystem$0(HdfsEnvironment.java:110)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.hdfs.authentication.NoHdfsAuthentication.doAs(NoHdfsAuthentication.java:25)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.hdfs.HdfsEnvironment.getFileSystem(HdfsEnvironment.java:109)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.hdfs.HdfsEnvironment.getFileSystem(HdfsEnvironment.java:102)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.filesystem.hdfs.HdfsFileSystem.directoryExists(HdfsFileSystem.java:254)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.filesystem.manager.SwitchingFileSystem.directoryExists(SwitchingFileSystem.java:117)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.filesystem.cache.CacheFileSystem.directoryExists(CacheFileSystem.java:104)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.filesystem.tracing.TracingFileSystem.lambda$directoryExists$5(TracingFileSystem.java:119)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.filesystem.tracing.Tracing.withTracing(Tracing.java:47)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.filesystem.tracing.TracingFileSystem.directoryExists(TracingFileSystem.java:119)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     at io.trino.plugin.hive.HiveMetadata.lambda$createSchema$22(HiveMetadata.java:951)
2024-05-08 09:17:45     ... 20 more
2024-05-08 09:17:45 
2024-05-08 09:17:45 
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.225Z    INFO    dispatcher-query-1      io.trino.event.QueryMonitor     TIMELINE: Query 20240508_071745_00002_vyeug :: FAILED (INVALID_SCHEMA_PROPERTY) :: elapsed 12ms :: planning 12ms :: waiting 0ms :: scheduling 0ms :: running 0ms :: finishing 0ms :: begin 2024-05-08T07:17:45.211Z :: end 2024-05-08T07:17:45.223Z
2024-05-08 09:17:45 2024-05-08T07:17:45.430Z    DEBUG   http-client-node-manager-63     io.trino.connector.CatalogPruneTask     Pruned catalogs on server: http://172.21.0.14:8080/v1/task/pruneCatalogs

The alluxio jars, I have even added more in a trial and error one by one, are included in both of Trino and Hive metastore containers:
[trino@4515602f2e82 hive]$ pwd
/usr/lib/trino/plugin/hive

[trino@4515602f2e82 hive]$ ls -ll | grep allu
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root         0 May  8 06:48 alluxio-2.9.3-client.jar
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  90338926 Mar 24  2023 alluxio-2.9.3-hadoop2-client.jar
-rw-r--r--  4 trino trino   519152 Jan  1  1980 alluxio-core-client-fs-312.jar
-rw-r--r--  4 trino trino  1499627 Jan  1  1980 alluxio-core-common-312.jar
-rw-r--r--  4 trino trino  6097283 Jan  1  1980 alluxio-core-transport-312.jar
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  90338925 May  8 07:06 alluxio-shaded-client-2.9.3.jar
-rw-r--r--  4 trino trino    34723 Jan  1  1980 trino-filesystem-cache-alluxio-445.jar


And

I would suggest to NOT mix spilling and file system caching for starters, they are not designed to work together. Beyond that I would say that it completely depends on what your queries are, what data they have to access, how your files and partitions are structured and how you define "expected". So I really cant answer with any more detail at this stage.

Thanks, @Manfred, for the quick suggestion. I have edited the question to provide more details.

Thanks, Manfred, the best take out is that spilling and caching are not meant to work together, and by finding caching has caused far fewer GetObjects, so at scale should be rewarding. On the other hand, I will continue optimizing the full table scans etc in the query plans.
